# Trouble with link to position in current file when capturing

Tags: org-mode, org-capture

So I'm fairly competent with org-mode, and I make constant use of custom templates. I'm just now exploring the idea of integrating capture into my programming work flow so I can whip up skeletons quickly and worry about details later. That being said, I've devised a template as follows:

```
("p" "Programming TODO" entry
            (file+headline "~/orgfiles/personalorg.org" "Tasks")
            "* %^{Description} 
             %i%a")
```

This seems to be working pretty well, except that whenever I try to click on the link it generates, I get a coderef error if there's real data there, or whatever the first match was if I capture on something like a comment. Since I can't seem to anchor the captures back to a point in the file, it's not very much more useful than just putting "TODO"s into the comments near the code.

Can someone explain what's going on here, and how I should work around this?